# Node added to stage/scene graph event?

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to add a `StackPane` to another `StackPane` at runtime and setting the width of the child `StackPane` to 800, but when I try to get the width of the child `StackPane`, it is showing as `0`.

Which is the event that gets fired from Javafx using which I can recognize that child node is added to scene graph with the desired properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) has [scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#sceneProperty) and [parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#parentProperty) properties. You can register a change listener on the scene property. When the value of the scene property changes to non-`null`, it means the node became part of a scene graph.

Note, however, that node's width and height will not return correct values until the next layout pass.

Comment: But i need to know a trigger/event/change listener where i should be able to get width and height of the node

Comment: @HermantS you can register a change listener on [widthProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#widthProperty--) and [heightProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#heightProperty--)